# Use KeyedList to goup items

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I have a small class written in C# to save a list of a data structure with a special key to group items.

```
public class KeyedList<TKey, TItem> : List<TItem>
{
    public TKey Key { protected set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Items { protected set; get; }

    public KeyedList(TKey key, IEnumerable<TItem> items)
        : base(items)
    {
        Key = key;
        Items = items;
    }

    public KeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping)
        :base (grouping)
    {
        Key = grouping.Key;
        ???
    }
}
```

Now I want to access the elements.

So what I have to write at the ??? to get the informations to Items?

Comment: Something like `Items = grouping.Select(g => g);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not store Items at all, because they are already handled by base class: `List<TItem>`.

But if you really want to do that, you can assing `grouping` to `Items` directly, because `IGrouping<TKey, TItem>` implements `IEnumerable<TItem>`:

```
public KeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping)
    :base (grouping)
{
    Key = grouping.Key;
    Items = grouping;
}
```

You can also point `Items` property to the `KeyedList` instance itself, because it implements `List<TItem>`:

```
public KeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping)
    :base (grouping)
{
    Key = grouping.Key;
    Items = this;
}
```